# Is there a way to push an object to an array from an object? (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I was trying to make a game to start learning JavaScript and i encounter this problem that i couldn't find an answer for it.
Basically, i want to push an already created object, in this case ''firstIPGenerator'' to an array called ''IPGenerators'' that is inside another object which is called ''player''. For some reason, it says that the ''IPGenerators'' array is ''Undefined''

```js
//This will declare the player
var player = {
    IPPoints: 0,
    IPGenerators: [],
    EXPPoints: 10,
    EXPGenerators: [],
    XPEPoints: 10,
    XPEGenerators: [],
    PEXPoints: 10,
    PEXGenerators: []
}

//This will declare the first IPGenerator of the game
var firstIPGenerator = {
    cost: 5,
    mult: 1,
    amount: 0,
    bought: 0
}

//This will declare the first EXPGenerator of the game
var firstEXPGenerator = {
    cost: 5,
    mult: 1,
    amount: 0,
    bought: 0
}
//This will push the already created ''firstIPGenerator'' to the ''IPGenerators'' array
player.IPGenerators.push(firstIPGenerator)

//This will push the already created ''firstEXPGenerator'' to the ''EXPGenerators'' array
player.EXPGenerators.push(firstEXPGenerator)

console.log(player);
```

At the same time, ''player'' is going to the index.js that is creating the Vue

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
    data: {
        message: 'Hola Pibe',
        player: player
    },
    methods: {
    
    }
})
```

And here is the HTML Code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
   
    <title>Incrementalism</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="IPPoints-container">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        <div class="IPPointsGen-container">
            <!--This will print the cost of every IPGenerator-->
            <div class="generator IPPoints-generator" v-for="IPGenerators in player.IPGenerators">
                {{ IPGenerators.cost }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--From here it's not important-->
        <div class="triGenPoints-container">
            <div class="EXPPoints-container">

            </div>
            <div class="XPEPoints-container">

            </div>
            <div class="PEXPoints-container">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="triGenerators-container">
            <div class="triGenerator EXPPoints-generator" v-for= "EXPPoints in player.EXPPoints">
                {{ EXPGenerators.cost }}
            </div>
            <div class="triGenerator EXPPoints-generator">

            </div>
            <div class="triGenerator EXPPoints-generator">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="js/player.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm really new to all of this so i'll thank everyone that can help

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else. Your code snippet works perfectly.

Comment: I pasted the whole solution so idk, maybe is there an extension that i missing?

Comment: I edited your question to make the snippet runnable and added a `console.log` statement to see the results. You can see it works fine. Your objects are pushed to the arrays. Any errors you have is with some other code.

Comment: Ok, i fixed the problem, since Vue is everything wrong or everything good there was an error in EXPGenerators part from the HTML. Thanks guys either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that you are referencing players without using "this".
The following should work.

```
this.players.IPGenerators.push(firstIPGenerator);
```

Items defined in the data method must be referenced using "this".

Comment: if that doesn't work try this:                                 
players.IPGenerators.push(firstIPGenerator);